# Angularjs $http get method not sending any params

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-http

I have created a jsfiddle, were i am tring to perform a http get using $http when clicked on the test button, The syntax and the structure of $http.get seems correct to me, but it is not sending the selected params (query string {data:$scope.newuser}) in the url.

here is the fiddle :

jsfiddle.net/8sZLs/2/

And at php side i tried 
, 
But not showing the values posted

Answer (score 7):

You cannot send an object with get, you need to make a post request as following.

```
 $http({
   url: 'request-url',
   method: "POST",
   data: { 'message' : message }
})
```

As @YauheniLeichanok suggested, another way is to use query parameters, `params` of `$http.get`, in this case the strings you pass will appear as: `?key1=value1&key2=value2`

Comment: Just as an option - you can also use 'params' instead of 'data' to append your data to the query string. It will work for GET.

Comment: @anvarik, can you tell me how to get this in the php side
<?php print_r($_POST['message']); ?>, not showing the values

Comment: @RaviMone, I am not familiar with PHP, but just use the following angular code: `$http.post('http://' + host + ':' + port + '/echo/html', $scope.newuser)` it should post your user

Answer (score 3):

Replace your $http.get line with this

```
$http.get('/echo/html/', {params:$scope.newuser});
```

Answer (score 1):

On how to get the values at the server side PHP.

Have to use php standard input

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
```