# How $http.get should work, I always get from PHP nothing right as answer

Tags: ajax, angularjs, get, file-get-contents

As I wrote in the title, I can't obtain any right answer from PHP. Anyone has any idea?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("appMovies", []);


app.controller("listMovies", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){

    getMovies($http);

}]);


function getMovies(_http){

    _http.get("movies.php", {data:{"getList":"LISTA"}})
        .success(function(data, status, header, config){
            console.log( data );
        })
        .error(function(data, status, header, config){
            //console.log(data, status, header, config);
        });

}
```

PHP

```
var_dump( file_get_contents("php://input") );
```

So, I got it... sorry my bad. Obviously $_GET fetch the data only from URL, so I should write

```
$http.get("movie.php/?getList=LISTA")...
```

Comment: why are you using `file_get_contents` for a GET request?

Comment: Yes I saw other example in here in that way

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing GET and POST requests. To use GET with Angular/PHP, you'll need to use `params` (query string parameters) instead of `data` (for POST bodies), and `_$GET` on the server (for query string parameters) instead of `file_get_contents("php://input")` (which gives POST body).

So in the browser, something like

```
_http.get("movies.php", {params: {"getList":"LISTA"}})
```

and on the server

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: I did, but it says undefined

Comment: Is "params" a special word for Angular or PHP?

Comment: "params" is an option for `$http`, as described at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Try it on another way:

```
$http.post("movies.php", {data: {"getList": "LISTA"}}).
        success(function (_data, _status) {
        })
        .error(function (_data, status) {
        });
```

And in your PHP-Code you can use then:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postData);
$request->_data;
```

Comment: Why should I use .post instead .get on javascript?

Comment: I'm using this functionality in my code, with the file_get_contents functionality. I had to much trouble with GET so I used my posted code

Comment: So $http.get is meant to be only to get data without any parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660012/angularjs-http-get-method-not-sending-any-params - reference to here.

The easiest way, is to use the .post event, there shouldn't be a problem on your side to use a .post instead of a .get or?

There you can grab the file_get_contents, also you can upload files via .post if you'll need it later async via Angular